# Need to prove or disprove an alternative group definition.

Tags: group-theory, axioms, semigroups

Let be the non empty set $G$ with the operation $*$ satisfy the following 3 conditions:

1. $a(bc) = (ab)c$, for all $a, b, c \in G$ (associative law).
2. For every $a,b$ there is $c$ such that $ac = b$. ($c$  is the "path" from $a$ to $b$).
3. For every $a,b$ there is $d$ such that $bd = a$. ($d$ is the "path back" from $b$ to $a$).

> Prove or disprove: $G,*$  is a group.

Asociativity:

Proof:

from 1)

Identity element:

Proof:

According to 2) For every $a,a$ there is $e$ such that $ae = a$.

Let proof $ea=a$.

According to 2) For every $e,e$ there is $X$ such that $eX= e$.

Let's check the two possibilites:

1. $X=a,$
2. $X\neq a$

If 1) then $ea=a$ proved.

If 2): $eX=e$ then what?

Every try failed. Someone can do it?

Comment: Are you sure you've copied down the axioms correctly? As written, I think the second two axioms are identical. Perhaps it should be that $\forall a,b \in G, \exists d \in G$ such that $db = a$?

Comment: "As written, I think the second two axioms are identical. "   <------ Absolutely not. In the Klein group it is  ac=b and b*c=a, in the Z4 group there is  ac=b and b*d=a

Comment: I think you're a bit confused, the statement is about whether these axioms are equivalent. If we take that for any two $a,b \in G \exists c \in G$ such that $ac = b$, then you can apply that axiom to the pair of elements $b,c$ and the second axiom guarantees the existence of an element, call it $d$ such that $bd = a$ which is exactly the statement of the third axiom.

Comment: Conditions two and three are certainly equivalent. The claim that they are “absolutely not” is incorrect, and the proffered “example” is nonsensical: groups certainly satisfy the two conditions, whether they are identical or not. To prove they are not identical, you would need to exhibit an example of a structure that satisfies one of the two conditions *but not the other*. You cannot do so, because they say the exact same thing, with the roles of $a$ and $b$ reversed. But $\forall a\forall b P(a,b)$ is equivalent to the formula s $\forall a\forall b P(b,a)$.

Answer (score 2):

If the third condition is written as

> For every $a,b \in G$ there is $d \in G$ such that $db=a$.

then the answer is that $G$ *is* a group and the existence of the identity element can shown as follows:

Fix $a \in G$. Then there exists $x_a$ and $y_a$ in $G$ such that $ax_a=a=y_aa$. We will prove that $gx_a=g=y_ag$ for any other $g \in G$. Indeed, if $g \in G$, since we know that there exists $x,y \in G$ with $ax=g=ya$, then $$gx_a = (ya)x_a = y(ax_a) = ya = g$$ and similarly $y_ag = g$. In particular $x_a=y_a$ (why?) and then $e := x_a (=y_a)$ is the identity element.

Comment: Why does the existence of $y_a$ follow from the axioms? Maybe I'm just missing something, but I don't see how that axioms guarantee the existence of an element which can be multiplied on the left to get from $a$ to $a$

Comment: @NoahSolomon Certainly, I misread the statement then. But isn't the third axiom the same as the second? Possibly a typo, or if not, then the answer is that $G$ is not necessarily a group.

Comment: I agree, I think as written the second and third axioms are identical

Comment: "But isn't the third axiom the same as the second? Possibly a typo, " <------ Absolutely not. In the Klein group it is ac=b and bc=a, in the Z4 group there is ac=b and bd=a

Comment: @csounder5 see my response to your other comment. The group properties of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} $ are not in question here, only whether the two axioms are equivalent

Comment: @csounder5 I don't understand your counterexamples. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: "I don't understand your counterexamples. Can you elaborate more? "  <----- I'll try: In the Klein group if you "go from" a to b through c, that means ac=b, then you "come back" from b to a, "through" the same c. That means bc=a. In the two cases c is a sort of "path". It's displayed in the Cayley table. In the Z4 group 2+3 =1, the "path" from 2 to 1 is 3,  and to "come back" from 1 to 2, the "path" is NOT 3, but 1. So if ac=b, must not be bc=a, but it may be different as bd=a, so the 3rd axiom is NOT as the 2nd axiom.

Comment: @csounder5 I understand what you mean, what happens is that you are reading the third axiom incorrectly. What do you want to express can be written as follows: for every $a,b \in G$ there is $c \in G$ such that $ac=b$ and $bc=a$. Where did you get that problem from? I'm pretty sure it's misspelled, because actually the second and third axioms are the same, with the only difference in the order of the symbols.

Comment: "for every a,b∈G there is c∈G such that ac=b and bc=a."  <------ this is ONLY true for the Klein group!!! In Z4 it's as i showed before: 1+3=2 AND 2+1= 3. The "path to go"  is +3 and "the path to come back"  is +1. I think it's better to leave the matter here. We will not agree :-)

Comment: Precisely what I am trying to say is that statement "for every $a,b \in G$ there is $c\in G$ such that $ac=b$ and $bc=a$" is what you mean and that is not what the problem refers to. What book did you get this problem from?

Comment: "What book did you get this problem from?"  <---- from no book, just from my head." "for every a,b∈G there is c∈G such that ac=b and bc=a" is what you mean"   <---- this is only in the Klein group. Not in Z4